# pg_restore does not work with unknown error message

Tags: postgresql

I tried to pg_dump from Postgresql 12.6 and pg_restore to Postgresql 14.5.
What I want is to move one table.

Here is the pg_dump command

```
pg_dump -Fc -b -U postgres -t test_eu3 -f C:\Users\...\Desktop\test_eu3.sql rulings
```

Here is the pg_restore command

```
pg_restore -v -U app_admin -d pre_rulings -t test_eu3 test_eu3.sql
```

Here is a message after hitting pg_restore command.

```
C:\Users\...>pg_restore -v -U app_admin -d pre_rulings -t test_eu3 test_eu3.sql
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
Password:
pg_restore: implied data-only restore
pg_restore: processing data for table "public.test_eu3"
pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: from TOC entry 2915; 0 3097390 TABLE DATA test_eu3 postgres
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  ????????????"public.test_eu3"??????????s
Command was: COPY public.test_eu3 (id, "national", item_day, item_hs_all, item_hs2, item_hs4, item_hs6, item_place, image_amount, img_name_all, item_image, other_info, org_discription, org_discription2, eng_discription, eng_discription2, id2) FROM stdin;
pg_restore: warning: errors ignored on restore: 1

C:\Users\...>
```

It seems pg_dump woks without any problem, but pg_restore does not work with error message of "public.test_eu3" I don't know what it's indicating "public.test_eu3"?.

I've read [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) and [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) but it seems there is no solution for this problem.

How can I restore the database?
I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Here is a message after hitting ALTER ROLE app_admin SET lc_messages = 'C'; command and restore.

```
postgres=# ALTER ROLE app_admin SET lc_messages = 'C';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# \q

C:\Users\enosh>pg_restore -v -U app_admin -d pre_rulings -t test_eu3 test_eu3.sql
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
Password:
pg_restore: implied data-only restore
pg_restore: processing data for table "public.test_eu3"
pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: from TOC entry 2915; 0 3097390 TABLE DATA test_eu3 postgres
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "public.test_eu3" does not exist
Command was: COPY public.test_eu3 (id, "national", item_day, item_hs_all, item_hs2, item_hs4, item_hs6, item_place, image_amount, img_name_all, item_image, other_info, org_discription, org_discription2, eng_discription, eng_discription2, id2) FROM stdin;
pg_restore: warning: errors ignored on restore: 1
```

Comment: You have to change `lc_messages` to English to see the actual error message; your terminal does not seem to be configured for displaying the language currently configured.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe
I log in to psql and hit **SET lc_messages TO 'en_US.UTF-8';** but nothing changed. am I doing wrong?

Comment: You only changed the setting for that one database session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `lc_messages` is set to a language that your terminal cannot display. There are two options:

1. If you connect to PostgreSQL with a superuser, you can use the `PGOPTIONS` environment variable to override the setting during your `pg_restore`. On Unix-like systems, that would work as follows:

   ```bash
   export PGOPTIONS='-c lc_messages=C'
   pg_restore ...
   ```

   On Windows, you can use

   ```bash
   set PGOPTIONS="-c lc_messages=C"
   pg_restore ...
   ```

   This will produce English error messages.
2. If you don't connect to PostgreSQL with a superuser, you are not allowed to change `lc_messages`. In that case, your only option is to ask the database administrator to change `lc_messages` in `postgresql.conf` (and reload PostgreSQL), or to set the parameter on your user:

   ```
   ALTER ROLE app_admin SET lc_messages = 'C';
   ```